# I want to retrieve data from SharePoint list using c# and store them into SQL server DB tables. How can I do this?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, sql-server, c-sharp

```
using ( SPSite site = new SPSite ("http://somesite/sitename"))
{    
    SPWeb myWeb = site.OpenWeb();
    SPList target = myWeb.Lists["YourListName"];
    SPListItems items = list.Items;
    myWeb.Dispose();    
}
```

Will this work? After this, how will I insert the data into tables created in my database?

Comment: Does my below answer helped you?

Answer (score 1):

On google you will find so many ways to do this. Using your code it will be something like this:

```
using ( SPSite site = new SPSite ("http://somesite/sitename"))
{    
    using (SPWeb myWeb = site.OpenWeb())
    {
       SPList target = myWeb.Lists["YourListName"];
       SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems();
       DataTable dt = items.GetDataTable();
     }
}
```

Now once you got your result in DataTable you can insert data in SQL by **SQLBulkCopy** method or by iterating DataTable using **For loop**.
You can refer below link to move data from DataTable to SQL Table.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779475/insert-datatable-in-to-sql-table